# Typeahead.js deliver only first 5 results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I want to search in my json file only in field "value", but I get there only first 5 results. No matter what is typed, every time the same result.

My code is:

```
$(function() {

      var search_url = 'https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/post_1960.json';
      var search_input = $("#prefetch input.typeahead");

      var search = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: search_url,
        remote: {
          url: search_url + '?%QUERY.json',
          wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
      });

      $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'search',
        display: 'value',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: search.ttAdapter()
      });

    });
```

JSON structure:

```
[{
    "year": "1961",
    "value": "West Side Story",
    "tokens": [
      "West",
      "Side",
      "Story"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "1962",
    "value": "Lawrence of Arabia",
    "tokens": [
      "Lawrence",
      "of",
      "Arabia"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": "1963",
    "value": "Tom Jones",
    "tokens": [
      "Tom",
      "Jones"
    ]
  }]
```

Here is also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Is possible to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching with the wrong url. From http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

```
remote: {
  url: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
  wildcard: '%QUERY'
}
```

change

```
url: search_url + '?%QUERY.json',
```

to

```
url: 'https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/%QUERY.json'
```

Comment: It looks like typeahead.js prefetch method example is not working quite well. There is a response with 404 status when you search for random word "tom" for example in this page http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch. It won't work well on your page either but you should get some results. In my fiddle i am getting "tom jones" as a suggestion.

Comment: BTW in your fiddle you've missed a comma after the url and you are getting an exception: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" .. try to define remote like this:

remote: {
      url: 'https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
      wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }

Comment: I am glad i could help. Checkout the fiddle again. I added a working example with github's public api. It uses transform: function (test) { return test.items; } to prepare the response for the display and shows repositories' full name